# Why am I getting "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"?

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, odbc

From Java, I want to connect to an .ACCDB file in the server (DSN less) and I keep getting the error. I googled for few hours and could not find anything. Please help!

```
String sURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=DBQ=C:/test/theDB.accdb;READONLY=true;";

        try {   
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");          
            log.debug("url: "+sURL);                

            // create connection to database using connection string
            dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL);

}
catch(SQLException e) {
            //retry
            try{dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL);}
            catch(SQLException ex){
                // Now, it is real failing. Throw exception
                log.error("Fail second time",ex);
                throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
        } 
        return dbCon;
```

Here's the exception I get:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10] at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10] at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10] at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10] at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10] at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10] at java.sql.DriverManager.getCon...

Comment: Error: 
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10]
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10]
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10]
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10]
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10]
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10]
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getCon...

Comment: Never mind, I solved it. Thank you. This is just the java running version problem

Answer (score 0):

`DBQ=DBQ=C: ...` will probably cause problems. One `DBQ=` is sufficient.